# SNR contains $\log N$ term where $N$ stands for number of samples

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-power, signal-energy, independence

Sampling the signal$ $N times increases the signal energy by a factor of $N^2$ and the noise energy by a factor of $N$. Why? This explanation is written for 
              SNR(dB) = signal peak(dB) – noise floor(dB)- $10\log N$

Answer (score 2):

In the additive model $y=s+n$, when the signal is deterministic, it adds coherently over the "realizations". Hence, its variance $V(\sum s_n) = V(N s) = N^2  V( s)$. And when the noise $w$ is independent identically distributed (IID), then $V(\sum w_n) = NV( n) $. This is a classical result on the  [Variance of Uncorrelated Variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235829/variance-of-uncorrelated-variables).

You can find this classical result detailed in [Deriving the SNR for averaged signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_averaging). Warning, this does reach a limit when data is quantized, in other words the noise floor does not follow $1\sqrt{N}$, but plateaues.

Comment: I think the question is about that $-10 \log N$ term in the expression for SNR and not about why the noise behaves as $N$ while signal behaves as $N^2$.